# Connect EPOC with android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm working on a project using an Emotiv Epoc (A neural headset).It connects to the PC through a Bluetooth transceiver. After searching for the headset with my Android  I can't find the headset with my phone, and I'm not sure if a USB-to-mini-USB adapter would work since the transceiver is designed to connect to a computer not a mobile device.

So my question is, does anyone know of a way to pull the information from the transceiver the headset came with and emulate it with the phone?